# Python: How to cast based on type without needing to import the objects we need to verify type

Tags: python

Consider as a matter of an example the following function:

```py
import numpy as np

# module.py
def func(x):
    if isinstance(x, np.ndarray):
        x = x.tolist()
    assert isinstance(x[0], int)
    # do more stuff...
    return x
```

```py
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3], np.int16)
>>> func(x)
[1, 2, 3]
```

How can one implement the conditional casting without having to import numpy?

One way to do this would be to do:

```py
if str(type(x)) == "<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"):
    x = x.tolist()
...
```

but that solution feels fragile (depends on the stability of the `__str__` method).

Any less fragile ways to do this?

*Appendix to deflect likely (but useless) responses: I know duck typing, `hasattr`, and don't want to go into details of why I want to avoid the imports in the first place.*

Comment: Unconditionally do `x = x.tolist()`, inside a `try` block that ignores AttributeErrors?  If some other class than `numpy.ndarray` has such a method, it seems likely that you'd actually need to call it for your code to work.

Comment: @jasonharper, that's duck typing. If there's many if clauses, it becomes ugly (and inefficient), and depends on the assumption that `tolist` means what we want it to mean if it exists.